Can't get User table to update sqlite database from user profile page - Python Flask Sqlite
I am currently trying to build a user profile page with Python using Flask and SQlite. I've managed to create the profile page to display the current users information. A button on the profile page takes the user to an "edit_account.html" page with a form to allow users to submit their info to change. Once the form is submitted, it redirects the user to their profile page, but all the info is the same, nothing has changed. It appears that the form does not actually change anything in the database.
I feel like I have two problems:

My profile page route function feels like I should be showing the profile page using the users ID. Instead, I'm just showing currently logged in user. It works, but it doesn't feel like the right way to do it for the next step. Example Instead of "/profile" should it say "/profile/username?
My "edit_account" func feels like I've got that wrong and I'm guessing that's why the database is not updating.

Truth is, I now can't see the wood for the trees and I'm in danger of making more of a mess without fixing. What I've tried:

I've tried adding "User.id" to the view function but this throws an error (can't remember the exact error message, something to do with undefined User maybe).
I've tried changing the html file to "User.id" and again I get an error.

What I'm trying to get to, is:

I want the profile page to automatically populate user info from the database.
I want the "edit_account" form to update the database with whatever fields the user chooses to update.
Then I want it to redirect the user back to their profile page to see their new info.

I have scoured this site, but the answers are not specific enough to my issue.
I know it's probably something simple and probably my poor coding, but I'm an enthusiast, not a pro.
All help greatly appreciated. :)
Views.py
@users.route('/edit_account', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_account():
    form = UpdateUserForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
    
        if form.picture.data:
            username = current_user.username
            pic = add_profile_pic(form.picture.data, username)
            current_user.profile_image = pic  
    
        db.session.commit(User.id)
        flash('Your account has been updated')
        return redirect(url_for('users.profile'))

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.username.data = current_user.username
        form.email.data = current_user.email
        form.password.data = current_user.password_hash
        form.fname.data = current_user.fname
        form.lname.data = current_user.lname
        form.phone.data = current_user.phone
        form.address.data = current_user.address
        form.postcode.data = current_user.postcode

        db.session.commit()
    
    profile_image = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/'+current_user.profile_image)
    return render_template('edit_account.html', profile_image=profile_image, form=form)

@users.route('/profile')
@login_required
def profile():
    return render_template('profile.html',)

Models.py
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(id)

class User(db.Model,UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    fname = db.Column(db.String, unique=False, nullable=True)
    lname = db.Column(db.String, unique=False, nullable=True)
    phone = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    address = db.Column(db.String, unique=False, nullable=True)
    postcode = db.Column(db.String, unique=False, nullable=True)
    profile_image = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=True, default='default_profile.png')
    role = db.relationship('Role', back_populates='user', lazy=True)
    posts = db.relationship('BlogPost', back_populates='user', lazy=True)

    def __init__(self,email,password, username, fname, lname, phone, address, postcode):
            self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)
            self.email = email
            self.username = username
            self.fname = fname
            self.lname = lname
            self.phone = phone
            self.address = address
            self.postcode = postcode

Forms.py
class UpdateUserForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[])
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[])
    picture = FileField('Update profile picture', validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg','png'])]) 
    fname = StringField('First name', validators=[])
    lname = StringField('Last name', validators=[])
    phone = StringField('Phone', validators=[])
    address = StringField('Address(excluding postcode)', validators=[])
    postcode = StringField('Postcode', validators=[])
    submit = SubmitField('Confirm Update')

Profile.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container emp-profile">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="profile-img">
                    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/'+current_user.profile_image )}}" alt="Profile Picture">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="profile-head">
                            <h5>
                                {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                                Meet {{ current_user.username }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </h5>

                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                            <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">About</button>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                            <button class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profile-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Timeline</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ url_for('users.edit_account', id=current_user.id) }}" class="profile-edit-btn"  name="btnAddMore">Edit Profile</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="profile-work">
                    <p>ABOUT</p>
                    <h6>Name: {{ current_user.fname }}</h6><br/>
                    <a href="">Bootsnipp Profile</a><br/>
                    <a href="">Bootply Profile</a>
                    <p>SKILLS</p>
                    <a href="">Web Designer</a><br/>
                    <a href="">Web Developer</a><br/>
                    <a href="">WordPress</a><br/>
                    <a href="">WooCommerce</a><br/>
                    <a href="">PHP, .Net</a><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="tab-content profile-tab" id="myTabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Username</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>{{ current_user.username }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Name</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>{{ current_user.fname }} {{ current_user.lname }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Email</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>{{ current_user.email }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Phone</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>{{ current_user.phone }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Profession</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>Driving Instructor</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Teaches</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>Manual Gearbox</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Hourly Rate</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>£40/hr</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Car</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>Audi A1 TFSI Sportback 2019</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Years of experience</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>1yr</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Availability</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <p>6 months</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label>Your Bio</label><br/>
                                <p>Your detail description</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>           
</div>

{% endblock %}

Edit_account.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container emp-profile">
    <div class="p-5 mb-4 bg-body-tertiary rounded-3">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold">Edit Profile</h1>
            <div class="container-fluid clearfix">
                <img class="rounded float-end img-thumbnail" style="max-width: 16vw;" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/'+current_user.profile_image )}}" alt="Profile Picture">
            </div>
                <div class="container-fluid py-5">
                    <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.username.label(class='form-label') }}
                            {{ form.username(class='form-control') }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.email.label(class='form-group') }}
                            {{ form.email(class='form-control') }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.password.label(class='form-label') }}
                            {{ form.password(class='form-control') }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.fname.label(class='form-label') }}
                            {{ form.fname(class='form-control') }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.lname.label(class='form-label') }}
                            {{ form.lname(class='form-control') }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.phone.label(class='form-label') }}
                            {{ form.phone(class='form-control') }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.address.label(class='form-label') }}
                            {{ form.address(class='form-control') }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.postcode.label(class='form-label') }}
                            {{ form.postcode(class='form-control') }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.picture.label(class='form-group') }}
                            {{ form.picture(class='form-control') }}
                        </div><br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.submit(class='btn btn-primary') }}
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}


Ok so I've got it working and so far, so good. The changes I made were to the "profile" route in the views file. I'd neglected to make a call to the database to pull the current_user details. I also neglected to include my form fields under "validate_on_submit" in the "edit_account" route, again in views.py.
Once I'd figured that out from a couple of Youtube videos, it worked!
New views.py
@users.route('/profile')
@login_required
def profile():
    profile = User.query.filter_by(username=current_user.username).first_or_404()
    return render_template('profile.html', profile=profile)

@users.route('/edit_account', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_account():
    form = UpdateUserForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        current_user.username = form.username.data
        current_user.email = form.email.data
        current_user.fname = form.fname.data
        current_user.lname = form.lname.data
        current_user.phone = form.phone.data
        current_user.address = form.address.data
        current_user.postcode = form.postcode.data
        if form.picture.data:
            username = current_user.username
            pic = add_profile_pic(form.picture.data, username)
            current_user.profile_image = pic  
        
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your account has been updated')
        return redirect(url_for('users.profile'))
    
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.username.data = current_user.username
        form.email.data = current_user.email
        form.fname.data = current_user.fname
        form.lname.data = current_user.lname
        form.phone.data = current_user.phone
        form.address.data = current_user.address
        form.postcode.data = current_user.postcode
        
        db.session.commit()
        
    profile_image = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/'+current_user.profile_image)
    return render_template('edit_account.html', profile_image=profile_image, form=form)

